# ngTagsInput Autocomplete does not Open

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, ng-tags-input

I am unable to get the AutoComplete list to display. My service returns json model: TagID: 1, text:MyText
but the AutoComplete list never displays.  My HTML:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" tag-class="{even: $index % 2 == 0, odd: $index % 2 != 0}" on-tag-added="addTag(tags)"> <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete> </tags-input>
```

My Controller code:

```
$scope.loadTags = function ($query) {
  var tags;
  contractorService.gettags()
  .success(function (data) {
    tags = data;
    return tags.filter(function(tag) {
    return tag.text.toLowerCase().indexOf($query.toLowerCase()) != -1
```

> UPDATE

I have discovered that it just does not like the Json returned from Ajax call to MVC Controller.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetMajorTags()
    {
        majorId = UserInfo.intMajorID;
        var tags = await CompanyClient.GetAvailableTags(majorId);
        return Json(tags, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Even bypassing the service and calling the MVC Controller method directly like below:

```
    $scope.loadTags = function (query) {
    return $http.get('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetMajorTags');

};
```

If I make the source static like below:

```
    var auto = [
    { TagID: 4,text: 'Tag4' },
    { TagID: 5, text: 'Tag5' },
    { TagID: 6, text: 'Tag6' }
];
```

It works, but it will not show what is returned from the MVC Controller even though the data returned is in the EXACT same format.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is there a return statement in your `loadTags` method? That does not make sense in the context of a service callback.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not correct:

```
$scope.loadTags = function ($query) {
  var tags;
  contractorService.gettags()
  .success(function (data) {
    tags = data;

    // return where?
    return tags.filter(function(tag) {
      return tag.text.toLowerCase().indexOf($query.toLowerCase()) != -1
    });
  });
}
```

There is no reason to have a return statement within your `success` callback. Where would that return to? If you did something like this:

```
var tags = $scope.loadTags();
console.log(tags);  // undefined
```

... tags would be undefined. The reason is because the return statement is NOT returning from the call to `loadTags`. It is instead returning from within a promise callback.

This is actually how it's done:

```
var tags = [];
$scope.loadTags = function () {
  contractorService
    .gettags()
    .success(function (data) {
      tags = data;
      tags =  tags.filter(function(tag) {
        return tag.text.toLowerCase().indexOf($query.toLowerCase()) != -1;
      });
    });
};
```

Notice how there are no return statements (except for your filter).

This just does not work at all:

```
$scope.loadTags = function (query) {
  return $http.get('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetMajorTags');
};
```

If you were to do something like this:

```
var tags = $scope.loadTags();
console.log(tags);  // promise object. NO DATA
```

`tags` would contain a promise object NOT your data. You would need to do the following to get the actual data:

```
 var tags = [];
 $scope.loadTags().success(function(data) {
   tags = data;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @JoelCDoyle none of it works.  My original code (with promise) was      $scope.loadTags = function ($query) {
        var tags;
        contractorService.gettags()
        .success(function (data) {
            tags = data;
                 tags.filter(function(tag) {
                    return tag.text.toLowerCase().indexOf($query.toLowerCase()) != -1;
                });
            });
    };  which didn't work.

Comment: Then I tried     $scope.loadTags = function (query) {
        $http.get('/SSQV4/SSQV5/Contractor/GetMajorTags')
            .then(function(res) {
                return res.data;
            });
    };  Which didn't work.  The data comes back, but it will not display in th auto complete list.  Only the static text will display in the list.